How to show restart page while react app building
How to show another html (like restart.html) while react app builds?
Currently it shows:

I use nohup serve -s build > nohup.out& and npm run buid commands.
I've tried to make config file as ChatGPT suggested, but it always redirects to restart.html, even if app not building. Config sample:
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/*",
      "destination": "/restart.html"
    }
  ]
}


can you share your ngnix.conf file?
